# Nebular NbSpinner inside button doesn't work

Tags: typescript, nebular, ngx-admin

I am trying to implement Nebular Spinner inside a button and it wont work. Once the button is clicked the spinner should display inside the button, only that it does not

I haven not got a clue why it does not work. I am following the examples given in the Nebular GitHub to no avail.

The spinner should show when the button is clicked as I change the value of the spinner flag inside the click event. 
Here's the Code

```
<button nbButton status="danger" [nbSpinner]="isWorking" nbSpinnerStatus="danger" type="submit"
                  [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" class="btn btn-block m-t-40 login-input login-input-button">
         Sign In
    </button>


    login(): void {
    this.isWorking = true;

    this.authService.login(credentials)
      .subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          // tslint:disable-next-line: no-console
          console.log(res);
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
          this.isWorking = false;
        }
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you init the variable `isWorking`?
You should init that variable as false in `OnInit` method.

```html
<button nbButton status="danger" [nbSpinner]="isWorking" nbSpinnerStatus="danger" type="submit" (click)="login()" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" class="btn btn-block m-t-40 login-input login-input-button">
         Sign In
</button>
```

... and in .ts

```js
    export class xxx implements OnInit {
      isWorking = false;
    // ...
      login(): void {
          this.isWorking = true;

          this.authService.login(credentials)
            .subscribe(
              (res: any) => {
                // tslint:disable-next-line: no-console
                console.log(res);
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
                this.isWorking = false;
              }
            );
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine for component.html:

```
   <button nbButton status="danger" [nbSpinner]="isWorking" nbSpinnerStatus="danger" (click)="login()" class="btn btn-block m-t-40 login-input login-input-button">
  Sign In
</button>
```

Please dont forget to import nbButton and nbSpinner in the current module that uses the component, for example :

```
   import {
  NbButtonModule,
  NbSpinnerModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';

    @NgModule({
  imports: [
    NbButtonModule,
    NbSpinnerModule
  ]
```